# Add items to particular OS X keychain other than the default

Tags: macos, cocoa, keychain

I am developing a macOS application. I am creating my own keychain. The keychain file is stored at a particular location on the Disk. Every time I launch the application, I have to write and read data from this keychain.

I am unable to find the correct way to add items to this particular keychain. I am using [`SecItemAdd()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1401659-secitemadd?language=objc). I want to specify to which keychain `SecItemAdd()` should add the item.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `SecKeychainSetDefault`? From it's [description](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1393097-seckeychainsetdefault?language=objc):

> In most cases, your application should not need to set the default keychain, because this is a choice normally made by the user. You may call this function to change where a password or other keychain items are added, but since this is a user choice, you should set the default keychain back to the user specified keychain when you are done.

Of course you will need other calls to obtain the `SecKeychainRef` argument this call requires etc., e.g. `SecKeychainOpen`, `SecKeychainCopyDefault`.

HTH